# Como recargar contenido en angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular7

yo tengo una noticias donde muestro un titulo y una descripcion. pasa que esta la toma de la db y la muestra. cuando borro o agrego un contenido me toca cambiar de ruta para poder apreciar el cambio de si agregue o modifique noticia desde la db directamente. Alguna idea de como actualizar visualemente tambien ?

Servicio

```
export class NoticiasService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

  headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  });

  mostrarnoticias() {
    const url_api = "http://localhost/apixeoms/mostrarnoticias.php";
    return this.http.get(url_api);
  }

}
```

Componente TS

```
export class NoticiasComponent implements OnInit {

  noticia=null;

  constructor(private http:NoticiasService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.obtenernoticias()
  }

  obtenernoticias() {
    this.http.mostrarnoticias().subscribe(
      data =>  this.noticia=data
    );
  }

}
```

Componente Html

```
<div class="container" style="background:blue;" *ngFor="let noticia of noticia">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" >
     <p style="text-align:center;">{{noticia.titulo}}</p>
     <p>{{noticia.contenido}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Aqui lo hice con la ayuda que me brindaste en angular 7

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NoticiasService} from '../service/noticias.service';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/internal/Observable";
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'; 
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-noticias',
  templateUrl: './noticias.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./noticias.component.css']
})
export class NoticiasComponent implements OnInit {

  noticias$: Observable<any>;


  constructor(private http: NoticiasService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.noticias$ = interval(1000).pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.http.mostrarnoticias()))
  }

}
```

me podrias mas o menos explicar que funcion hace el pipe y el switchMap ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tienes tres opciones:

**1) Async Pipe & Observables**

En este caso debes crear una variable de tipo observable que realice peticiones constantes a tu backend

```
 products: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.products = Observable
      .interval(1000)
      .startWith(0).switchMap(() => this.api.getProducts());
  }
```

en tu plantilla aplica el pipe async

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let product of products | async">{{ product.prod_name }} for {{ product.price | currency:'£'}}</li>
</ul>
```

**2) Sockets**

Aqui debes modificar tu backend e implementar alguna libreria que permita el manejo de sockets actualmente es muy usada socket.io

**3) Firebase**

Una solucion rapida es usar firebase, es rapido y no necesita mucha configuracion, en cuanto al cliente de angular no hay que hacerle nada.

Comment: la interval no me la reconoce. cual de las tres es la mejor opcion ?

Comment: Hola, las importaciones deben ser de 'rxjs/add/observable/*'; , la mejor opcion seria la No 2 si cuentas con los conocimientos y tienes control del backend, si son pruebas y queres algo rapido usa firebase

Comment: ya le puse la importacion y me da error

Comment: import { Observable } from "rxjs/internal/Observable"; como tengo esta no me deja colocar la otra

Comment: intenta con import { interval } from 'rxjs'; revisa la documentacion segun la version de angular que tengas

Comment: el import me funciona pero me da error en las otras dos metodos. this.noticias$ =  interval(1000).startWith(0).switchMap(() => this.http.mostrarnoticias());

Comment: uso la ultima version de angular y la verdad no tengo conocimiento de esos metodos